# How to create an Ant's symlink with wildcard?

Tags: ant, wildcard, symlink, fileset

I've tried to create a symlink like:

> `<symlink link="${basedir}/docroot" resource="${basedir}/drupal-7.*" overwrite="true"/>`

however, the line doesn't expand the wildcard but creates a link which points literally to `drupal-7.*`, not to `drupal-7.56`.

I've tried to use [examples with `fileset` on this page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/symlink.html), but it doesn't really cover my scenario.

How can I create an Ant's symlink which points to a dynamic folder (the one expanded by `drupal-7.*`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`dirset`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html) instead of [`fileset`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) to include directories, not files. Also, it would probably be a good idea to check for an unexpected number of directories as well.

Here is the example:

```
<dirset dir="${basedir}" includes="drupal-7.*" id="link.target" />

<fail message="Multiple or zero drupal-7.* directories found.">
    <condition>
        <not>
            <resourcecount refid="link.target" when="equal" count="1" />
        </not>
    </condition>
</fail>

<symlink link="${basedir}/docroot" resource="${toString:link.target}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution by invoking shell command:

```
<exec executable="sh" failonerror="true" dir="${basedir}" outputproperty="drupaldir">
  <arg value="-c"/>
  <arg value="echo drupal-7*"/>
</exec>
<symlink link="${basedir}/docroot" resource="${basedir}/${drupaldir}" overwrite="true"/>
```